# Cómo manejar la conexión mongoDB

Tags: javascript, nodejs, api, mongodb

Actualmente estoy aprendiendo a crear API y empiezo a crear el servidor express y las rutas, ahora mi problema aparece cuando intento conectarme a mi mongoDB porque no estoy seguro de cómo manejar la conexión. Mi código es el siguiente.

Principal: aplicación.js

```
// * Modules required

const express = require('express');
const serverDatabase = require('./database')

serverDatabase.connectToMongoDB()

app = express()

app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

app.use('/api/v1/auth', authRoutes)

app.listen(8000, () => {

    console.log('Server listening on port: ' + serverPORTSelected);

})
```

Como puede ver, estoy llamando a la base de datos del servidor e iniciando el servidor express
Este es mi código en database.js

```
// * Modules Required

const mongodb = require('mongodb')

// * This function will try to connect to mongoDB Responding with the database 

function connectToMongoDB(){

    const client = new mongodb.MongoClient(process.env.dbURI)

         // * Trying the connection to the database

    try {

            const database = client.db('API-TEST')        
            console.log('Connected to database: ' + database.databaseName)              

    } catch (error) {

        console.error(`Something bad happened trying to connect to mongoDB`)
        console.error('');
        console.error('ERROR LOG');
        console.error('');
        console.error(error);

    }

}

module.exports = {
    connectToMongoDB:connectToMongoDB
}
```

Entonces, en este punto, la conexión funciona completamente bien, el problema surge cuando intento usarla en el enrutador, por ejemplo, /api/v1/auth' es manejado por auth Routes y en las rutas está el siguiente código

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

// * App Modules Required

const authControllers = require('../controllers/auth.controller')

router.get('/test', authControllers.test)

module.exports = router
```

ahora auth.Controller debe manejar la solicitud y esto es lo que tengo en el controlador

```
async function test(req,res) {        

    let testingCollection = databaseConnection.collection('users')

    const query = { userEmail: 'test@test.com' };
    const queryResults = await testingCollection.findOne(query);
    console.log(queryResults);

    res.json(queryResults)

}

module.exports = {
    test: test
}
```

Ok, mi gran problema está aquí, cuando llamo a databaseConnection hay un error que dice que databaseConnection no está definida y es porque la variable databaseConnectionno está en el archivo, así que mi pregunta es ¿cómo puedo hacer que databaseConnection sea accesible desde cualquier parte de la app?

Intente hacer un await para database.js y me respondi con la variable, probe y funciono, pero ¿cómo puedo pasar eso a los controladores?

¿Tendré que crear una conexión y cerrar la conexión para cada request?

Por cierto, no puedo usar mongoose porque los datos que guardaré son dinámicos, por lo que no puedo establecer un Schema.